# Importing fabric js components in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, office-ui-fabric

I have tried to install fabric-js components in my angular 4 project

using the commands

```
    npm install ng office-ui-fabric --save
```

provided in the link

```
    https://github.com/ngOfficeUIFabric/ng-officeuifabric#installation
```

I have followed all steps correctly,but i am still unable to find

```
     1)/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/fabric.css
     2)/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/fabric.components.css
```

in my node_modules folder.I am bit confused that how to to use fabric component in

```
    app.component.ts folder
```

Comment: did you import inside angular.conf json

Comment: No,there were no instruction regarding angular.conf json

Comment: after installing did you import the css ?

Comment: i mean inside style.css did you import?

Comment: can you show your angular-cli.json or imported code

Comment: no i have not done anything inside the style.css and i have checked that there is no  
     1)/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/fabric.css
     2)/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/fabric.components.css                                             in node-modules folder

Comment: ok i will show angular-cli.json

Comment: I am unable to post,the code is too lengthy.

Comment: i have added answer try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step will be to open to the .angular-cli.json file and add your third party css files

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.css",
  "./node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.components.css"
  "styles.css"
]
```

If you want to add Js file then you have to add script inside your scripts array

```
"scripts": [
      "./node_modules/.../../../../.js"
    ]
```